# Xray extension slowing down Catalog

Tags: arcgis-desktop, performance, arccatalog

I recently installed Xray for Catalog and my Catalog has been insanely slow ever since. I've uninstalled the Xray extension but my Catalog is still slow.

Any suggestions to speed Catalog back up to normal?

Comment: Are you seeing this in ArcCatalog or in the Catalog window of ArcMap?  In any event, an expedient may be to uninstall/reinstall ArcGIS Desktop which takes about 30 mins.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably try starting with a new Normal.gxt file. Something might be going on there. Just make sure to back up the old Normal.gxt file too.

1. Close ArcCatalog.
2. Navigate to C:/Users/yourusername/AppData/Roaming/ESRI/Desktop10.X/ArcCatalog/
3. Rename Normal.gxt to Normal_backup.gxt
4. Start up ArcCatalog. This will create a new Normal.gxt and might resolve your speed issue. The catch is, if you have any custom configuration (menus, etc), these will reset to default but you can always revert back to your backup file if needed.

Comment: this is my first go to for performance issues after a recent install/add corruption